# Certain web page cannot be retrieved

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, web

I have a simple web site in php served over apache running on ARM Linux. It normally works fine. But sometimes, certain pages cannot be retrieved at all. I have 5-6 pages. All the other pages would work fine when this happens. There is no timeout error either. When it happens, Firefox or Chrome would just keep saying "Connecting..." forever. I tried `wget -v` and it says:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

and just hangs there.

I could telnet into the box and access the file locally without a problem so it's not a storage issue.

What's even more strange is:

- I logged into the box
- `cp foo.php foo1.php`
- Back at the client side, `wget -v foo1.php` has the same issue!

EDIT: More information

So I have a small embedded ARM computer that serves a few simple PHP web pages. The computer sit on a LAN behind a Sonicswall firewall/vpn router. Port forwarding is configured on the router to allow external access to the web server (port 80). Everything works fine to start with. After a few days, one of the page cannot be retrieved. Here are a few peculiar things about the problem:

1. Only external access is affected. All page are accessible from inside.
2. When the problem happens, Apache log doesn't show any request at all.
3. Rebooting the ARM computer and it'll work again.
4. It almost always happen to the same page, which happens to be named system.php.

So it's a bit of a mystery to me: if it's the firewall, the rebooting the ARM computer wouldn't help; if it's the ARM computer, then internal access would have the same problem.

I really haven't a clue what's going on. Could somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the apache access and error logs around the time frame that you're getting the error and see what they are reporting. I don't know enough about PHP to know if it logs errors separately from the web server, but if so, check the php logs for the same time frame.

With the details from the logs, it may be easier to discern what's going on with the server/pages.

Comment: The access.log doesn't show anything when this happens.

Comment: @lang2, PHP errors are normally written to the Apache error log, not the access log.

Comment: @John, if there is no access record in access log, the problem is before PHP, no?